# Is there a concise way to say "all of the X, one of each"?

Tags: phrase-request

So when you want to buy all of the donuts in a shop, but only one of each. You say: I want all of the donuts. The employee then ask you "all of them?" You tell him "No, one of each." Is there a faster way, a more concise way to say this in one spurt?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I respectfully disagree with the other answers. Your question is asking for a concise wording, and there is an equally clear and more concise way to express what you want (but please, read my notes at the bottom, and read all the other answers and comments as well).

### My answer

In the context of speaking to a person who sells different kinds of doughnuts, this wording is completely clear:

> One of each doughnut(, please).

It's not necessary to explicitly say "each *kind of* doughnut" at all, if you want to be concise. "One of each doughnut" can only be understood one way, and if someone spends their day selling doughnuts, I'll bet dollars to them that they hear this kind of phrasing often.

> One each of chocolate, cream-filled, and rainbow sprinkles, please.
>
> Three each of cinnamon and vanilla icing, thanks.
>
> Two of each iced doughnut, thanks.

The exact thing you're referring to isn't important here—doughnuts, pizzas, flowers, anything that is in obvious groups, types or kinds would make sense this way.

> One each of Hawaiian and Pepperoni to take away, please.
>
> I can't decide between your cakes! One slice of each, please!

### Even shorter

As pointed out in other answers and comments (too many names to mention directly), there may be an even more concise option:

> One of each (, please)

This would probably be understood just fine in context, so long as you're standing in a shop that really does sell *nothing but doughnuts*. I really cannot imagine that shop—but yes, if it is a really specialized business, that would be fine. And worst case, here's your conversation:

> One of each, please.
>
> You want one of every doughnut and muffin?
>
> Oh, no, sorry. Just the doughnuts, thanks.
>
> No problem.

This exchange is not more concise than your example in the question, but it is a successful communication event without meaningful misunderstanding, and is the kind of conversation a shopkeeper has all the time.

### Why is there so much debate on this question?

[Comments](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) aren't the right place for extended discussion. So for the benefit of future learners reading this, I want to briefly discuss some reasons why I'm so comfortable with *one of each doughnut*, and why so many other people here aren't.

***This is not meant in the spirit of debate and riposte; it's meant as a brief didactic look at some points and counterpoints.*** Nor is it intended to be exhaustive, definitive, or to rebuke any of the disagreements.

#### Concise vs precise

Communicating [concisely](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/concise) is different to communicating [precisely](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/precise). Even if the question hadn't explicitly asked for a concise wording, in casual speech speakers err towards **more concise, less precise** wording *almost without exception*.

Real-world spoken English is more holes than it is cloth. English speakers enthusiastically drop out pretty much anything that can be understood from context, create new contractions, and commit all kinds of grammatical sins, and yet they are still consistently understood. They don't do it consciously, and when they hear another person speaking that way in the real world, they don't think about it consciously either. We rarely need to be *precise* in speech, and so we usually choose to be *concise*.

#### Context is king

All communication is about context. If the question was: "I want to order doughnuts over the phone from a bakery that sells all kinds of pastries and desserts," then the answer would be very different. Some of the answers here have made different assumptions about the context of the dialogue. If it isn't obvious what you're asking the person for, you'll need to be more *precise* about how you ask.

#### Polite and impolite speech

Generaly speaking, in English, polite speech uses more words. Many languages have a grammatical way to speak formally or politely to someone—for example, second person plural (like French), third person (like Italian), even totally different vocabulary and grammar (like Japanese).

English doesn't have a single, clear grammatical rule about politeness that's the same everywhere. What is polite and what is rude changes in deferent contexts, and it changes *a lot* in different places. If you accidentally speak impolitely, it will prevent you from being understood clearly (and will also just not be nice).

So if it isn't common *where you are* to drop the words **kind of** from a phrase like **one of each kind of doughnut**, then you're going to sound both confusing and rude. As a learner, it is good advice to be careful about being *too concise*.

Comment: This works, but not because it's right, but because people can understand what you meant even though it's not what you said. For example, if you have a pepperoni pizza and two Hawaiian pizzas, there's a clear difference between a "one slice of each pizza" and "one slice of each kind of pizza". You're basically saying something non-sensical when you say "one of each donut", but because there's only way to modify your sentence to make it fit, it still works.

Comment: It isn't non-sensical at all. We omit and elide parts of speech that are not required for clarity all the time. This is simply the elision in casual speech of an obviously implied *kind of* between *each* and *doughnut*.

Comment: To me, it definitely goes "oh wait, that doesn't make sense", then "oh, they probably mean that", so it's not as obvious (at least to me) as you imply.

Comment: I think you can get even more concise. Simple "one of each" in a donut shop is clear and concise

Comment: @Jasper: Type/kind/... is an incredibly common omission that is found in everyday speech. While you are correct that the phrase by itself can be ambiguous as to whether the speaker is focusing on the omitted "kind" or the objects themselves, it is colloquially used and the intended meaning is usually contextually clear anyway. It makes no sense to want to have a physical portion of every physical donut in the shop. It makes considerably more sense for a customer to want one of each type of donut in the shop. Context is key.

Comment: @Johnny "One of each doughnut" is thoroughly ambiguous and not very logical, but you might hit lucky and get what you want. "One of each kind" is more natural; though it depends on a shared understanding of how doughnuts are classified, e.g. it could still cause problems if there are orthogonal variations in size, flavour, topping, etc.

Comment: had to change my best answer after reading this one.

Comment: @Johnny: so... you have one piece of something (doughnut), and then you want "one piece of each"?! Can you please explain how does this make sense? How is it better than "one of each **kind**"?

Comment: @MichaelKay I disagree. As somebody who's sold things from a counter, "one of each kind" sounds very unnatural to me and I know few people who use English as a first language who would say that. As Flater points out, the context of the situation tends to make things very clear. If I go up to a doughnut stand and say "one of each, please", what else could I reasonably be referring to?

Comment: @DoctorPenguin In my opinion, there's a big difference between "one of each" (omitting "kind of donut" at the end) and "one of each donut" (omitting "kind" in the middle)

Comment: @Jasper in what way? I still couldn't see as a vendor what else they could reasonably be referring to. That said, I do think the former statement is more natural and versatile.

Comment: @DoctorPenguin If the shop only sells doughnuts, that's clear. If the shop sells doughnut, cupcakes and muffins and you only say "one of each", you'll end up buying a lot more than you actually asked.

Comment: @DoctorPenguin In the sense that "one of each" feels natural and logical to me, while "one of each donut" does not. So, then, "one of each" may be the most logical thing to say, unless - like ChatterOne says - they also sell other things than donuts, in which case I'd say "one of each *kind* of donut" (despite both versions with omissions being functionally clear enough)

Comment: @Jasper Yeah, I pretty much agree with that. I'd use "one of each X" as clarification if somewhere sold Y and Z too, but just "one of each" if they only sold X. Sorry, I was under the impression you were saying that they functionally meant something different.

Comment: For the benefit of non-native speakers, the answer's use of "I'll bet dollars to them..." is a joke, based on the set phrase "[bet dollars to *donuts*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bet_a_dollar_to_a_doughnut)" (so the antecedent of the pronoun "them" is the "donuts" being sold). This is funny because the donuts in "dollars to donuts" are rhetorical, but in this instance we are talking about actual donuts. Anyway, it made *me* laugh. `:)`

Comment: @apsillers Glad that made someone other than me chuckle! :)

Answer (score 8):

### Just 3-5 Words Needed

If it's a donut shop in the US, the phrase `one of each` is usually sufficient. The rest is just tacking on politeness or disambiguation. Even if the store also sells crullers and other things, `Donuts, please. One of each.` would be reasonably polite and unambiguous. For example:

> Cashier: Welcome to Week-Old Donuts. What would you like?
>
> Customer: Donuts, please. One of each.
>
> Cashier: Coming right up.

Comment: Much more idiomatic, closer to the way people actually talk in donut shops (and doughnut shops for that matter).

Answer (score 6):

Another variant:

> (I want / I'll buy) one doughnut of each kind (that you have / that's for sale) (, please).

Everything in the parentheses is optional, but useful, though.

For even shorter than that, you will need to search a different language :)

Comment: I would expect any English speaker to understand me if I said "One of each doughnut, please," or "Three of each doughnut, please."

Comment: They will understand if you are lucky. But even if "any English speaker" (assuming a native English speaker) is able to understand you, what if the guy with the donuts is actually a foreigner with limited English capabilities? That's why you should make efforts to learn English better, not shorter, in order to be sure you can communicate unambiguously with anyone.

Comment: @virolino how could a non-native speaker misinterpret "one of each" (in a donut shop)? I can't see any ambiguity in it, but I'm a native speaker.

Comment: @virolino: Not understanding a statement in a language that you do not fully grasp is not the fault of the speaker - unless the speaker had previously been asked to account for this fact. Working in customer service, it is not appropriate to lay the blame with the customer for the CSR not grasping the language of the region. I have much sympathy for non-native-language speakers (I'm married to one and will soon move to her country, so I will then be a non-native-speaker), but the responsibility of speaking and understanding the local language is mine, it's not everyone else's. [..]

Comment: @virolino: [..] I cannot reasonably expect others to change their own native language on the off chance that they might run into a foreigner who might not have a perfect comprehension of the local language. That's not to saying that you can't asking for clarification if you are a non-native-speaker and did not understand something (of course you can do that!), but it's not right to pre-emptively expect everyone to already change their language in anticipation of that possible scenario.

Comment: @Kevin: The comment was made as an answer to "One of each doughnut" - which I would have difficulty understanding quickly. However, "One of each **kind** of doughnut" is a whole different thing.

Comment: @Flater: It is not about blaming here. If I let that impression, then I apologize. My point of view is: understandability and correctness should not be sacrificed for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @Johhny: your sentence is pretty much nonsensical, regardless of what the listeners **might** understand. How can you have "one piece of each" when choosing from exactly one piece of something countable (doughnut)?

Comment: @virolino: Don't you mean "understandability and correctness should not be sacrificed for the sake of brevity _unless verbosity adds an unreasonable risk that does not outweigh the benefits of avoiding potential misunderstandings; for example the ability to only send a short mesage in an emergency, among other possible situations_"? And that's my point: **brevity is relative** to what you contextually expect the listener to require to understand your message.

Comment: @virolino To anybody who speaks enough English to live and work in an English-speaking country, "one of each" already contains all the information they need. There is nothing that "one of each donut" could possibly mean, except "one of each kind of donut", so I really don't see what you're confused about.

Answer (score 3):

You can say "I want one of each of your doughnuts".

Comment: It's a bit too long though.

Comment: @frbsfok Seriously? It's eight words and nine syllables. Definitely don't say "Hello" or "please" or "thank you" because that's a whole lot more words.